# Touchpad only recognized when booting from recovery menu

Tags: drivers, kernel, touchpad

I have a Lenovo P14s laptop with Ubuntu 22.04.02 LTS dual-booted with Windows. My touchpad had been working fine until I connected it to a separate monitor/mouse/keyboard setup and disabled the laptop screen when connected. From the other threads on this matter I have tried the following with no success:

- restarting driver with 'sudo modprobe -r psmouse'. I get an error
  that the command does not exist
- downgrading the kernel (to an earlier
  version of 5.19 and even 5.15) via mainline
- checking if the touchpad
  is even recognized with 'xinput --list' (it was not)

The only thing that has worked is normal booting from the recovery menu, which has worked for all the different kernel versions. When booting from the recovery menu, the touchpad is recognized with xinput, and I can even restart the driver if I want. However, my system has trouble connecting to external peripherals then.